# Did each clan in Sengoku Japan have a specialty or distinctive way of war?

Tags: japan, warfare, samurai, sengoku

I know that the regions of Iga and Koga bred soldiers that excelled at guerilla warfare, The Takeda cavalry, The Otomo and Oda for their guns.

Were there other daimyo who were known for the way they fought or the styles of army they fielded?